# How are transaction fees computed

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

For example, how much would the fee be to send $350 to someone? The person is trying to tell me it would cost $270 for 225 bytes

Comment: A *person* is telling you this is the fee? Why is there a *person* involved? This makes me wonder if you are somehow caught up in a scam. Can you elaborate on the situation at all?

Answer (score 4):

The Bitcoin transaction fee depends on :

- The [size](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Weight_units) of the transaction
- The current feerate

The transaction fee in $ depends in addition on the price of a bitcoin in dollar.

Simply put, the size of the transaction *basically* depends on the number of time you received bitcoins in the past (if you want to send 350$ the transaction size will be higher if you received a hundred times 3.5$ than if you received ten times 35$). This is the number of [inputs of the transaction](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#Input).

The feerate depends on the [current demand for block space](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/96491/101498).

> The bytes were 225

The [**estimated**](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/96491/101498) fee rate for your transaction to be included in one of the next ten blocks (1h40) is **currently** of `0.00002121`btc / kilo[vbyte](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Weight_units).

The current price of a bitcoin in dollars is about 8800$ / btc.

This transaction would cost you about `0.042`$ (to be confirmed in the next ten blocks).

```
>>> 0.00002121 * 225 * 8800 / 1000
0.04199579999999999
```