# Set bitcoin fee lower than minimum estimatesmartfee value

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, bitcoin-cli

Currently when I broadcast transactions, I seem to be unable to do so with a fee below ~10^-4 bitcoin (~$2 at current exchange rate). Any 'conftarget' value between approximately 100 - 1000 yields the same ~10^-4 estimate. I would prefer to send some less urgent transactions with lower fees but it's not clear how to do so if when I set conftarget=1008 (which I believe is the bitcoin core max) for the transaction, I cannot access fees lower than described. Is this expected behaviour for Bitcoin Core?

On a related note, it is not completely clear to me how the `estimatesmartfee` 'estimate_mode' parameter functions. From the help, I can see that the options are 'ECONOMICAL' and 'CONSERVATIVE', which seem quite self-explanatory on a high level (former estimates lower fees than latter for same conftarget), but in practice - how does the estimation differ? So far I have used the default 'UNSET', which I understand defaults to 'CONSERVATIVE' - would this affect the value of the apparent minimum possible network fee described above?

Comment: Your post contains two questions, for the latter see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96489/how-does-bitcoin-core-estimate-the-transaction-fee/96491#96491 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, a new `fee_rate` argument has been added to the `sendtoaddress` command in the upcoming release (`v0.21.0`, currently at the third release candidate) of Bitcoin-Core.
In addition, a new `send` RPC was integrated which allows you to set a specific feerate too.

Regarding your second question (meaning of `CONSERVATIVE` and `ECONOMICAL`), see [How does Bitcoin Core estimate the transaction fee?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96489/how-does-bitcoin-core-estimate-the-transaction-fee/96491#96491) .